# What is the resultant resistance of the circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrical-resistance, electronics

If all resistants have a resistance of $R$, find the resultant resistance between points $AE$.

[image]

**My Try:**
Since Points AB and AC have equal resistance, There's an equal current flowing through each branch. So points B and C have equal voltage compared to point A. So we can delete resistant between B and C. Similarly resistant between C and D can be removed. So the top branch would yield $3R$. Bottom branch would yield $2R$. Since those two branches are parallel. Then resultant would be $\frac{6R}5$.
Is this method Correct?
Or can we just seperate nodes at C as in the following diagram to make it 'less complicate'?
[image]

Comment: Hi Emil and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'll ask for the concept instead of the answer.

Comment: One thing to look for is symmetry. In this case what can you infer about the potential of the node midway between Band D and the potential at node C?

Comment: They are equal. So we can break resistance in path BD into two $\frac{R}{2}$ 's and join midpoint of that to node C? Am I correct?

Comment: *"Since Points AB and AC have equal resistance, There's an equal current flowing through each branch."* - This would only be valid if you *stipulate* that the (node) voltage at B equals the voltage at C.  Concluding that which you stipulate is [begging the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question)